# Cross walk crash analysis

Tags: crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk, crosswalk-project

I have a couple of crash logs from the Android play store.
 The crash are in the cross walk library (libxwalkcore.so). Whats the process of obtaining the symbol file of the cross walk native library aamd cross reference this with the crash logs on the Android play store?